# Large data insertion

Tags: php

I have a csv file uploaded and data read into an array .The valid data is stored in the array
as  associative array indexed from 0-4000 records

```
Array
(


[0] => Array
        (
            [uname] => uname1
            [name] => fullname1
            [email] => uname1@email.com

        )
[1] => Array
        (
            [uname] => uname2
            [name] => fullname2
            [email] => uname2

        )
[2] => Array
        (
            [uname] => uname3
            [name] => fullname3
            [email] => uname3@email

        )
[3] => Array
        (
            [uname] => uname3
            [name] => fullname3
            [email] => uname3@email

        )
..
...


[3999] => Array
        (
            [uname] => uname3
            [name] => fullname3
            [email] => uname3@email

        )

)
```

How can i insert so many records because the `$array` is stored in variable when i click the submit the `$array` is reset to null.
How can I approach this without using database, any solution available?

Comment: You've had lots of answers to your previous questions. Please accept some, you'll be much more likely to get good answers in future if you do.

Comment: Where are you trying to insert the records?  "without using database"?

Comment: Insert where? Database? confused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to say you're overflowing the 64KB limit of the `<FORM>` when you submit it?  Make sure you're using `method="POST"` and `encoding="multipart/form-data"`.

It's also possibly, but highly unlikely with 4000 records, that you're exceeding the `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` parameters in your `php.ini` file.  If you're secretly trying to post 50 million email addresses instead then that's likely your problem.

If that doesn't help, then you need to clarify what you're trying to accomplish, because we're left guessing. ;)